# Embedding The Dart VM In A Desktop Graphical Stand - Alone Application

Tags: html, qt, desktop-application, dart, dartium

So I am writing a cross-platform (so far plans for Windows and Ubuntu) application for both the web and desktop.
This application
is expected to at times be moderately graphically intensive and perform a substantial amount of file IO. I am writing it in Dart. Which may seem like a
"funny" choice given the circumstances, however I did not want
to deal with any heavy API's or have two code bases (NaCl and GCC with two different libs).
In short I am using Dart to interact with an HTML web page, and noticed the Dart VM does
not interact with a webpage unless you are in Dartium. But I want a "desktop application" as  well as a web application which eliminates Dartium as a choice, so alternately I plan to use a Qt Webview to make it look like a desktop app, but what I am wondering is would it be worth it to go through the trouble of embedding the Dart VM into my app? In doing so would it easily enough to get the Dart VM (running a dart script) to interact with the page in the Qt Webview (I am a bit new to Dart)? Thanks for reading!

Comment: I hope that [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) project will be ported to Dart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dartium will eventually be merged with Chromium, allowing your DART applications to run inside chrome directly as a web technology.

Once that merges, you can take advantage of the new [Chrome Apps](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/about_apps.html) which allow you to have a desktop version of your web technologies. As such, you won't need to use Qt Webview, or embed dartVM into your native application; just use Chrome Apps.

~Main

Comment: Thank you so much! I was actually going to make something similar to Chrom Apps for another project. This is so helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: This isn't happening anymore http://news.dartlang.org/2015/03/dart-for-entire-web.html